# XslCompiledTransform Load method throw 'access denied exception'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, xslt, xslcompiledtransform

I have a WinForms application (x64) running under .Net 4.6.
I'm using `XslCompiledTransform` in order to manipulate some XML files using XSLT files.
The XSLT transformation is done in parallel for many XML files as follow:

```
Parallel.ForEach(totalBusWorkingFolderFileItem, po, (xsltPath, loopState) =>
{
     XmlTextWriter transformedXml = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
    // Create a XslCompiledTransform to perform transformation   
    XslCompiledTransform xsltTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();
    XsltSettings settings = new XsltSettings()
    {
        EnableDocumentFunction = true,
        EnableScript = true
    };
    lock (xsltCompilerLocker)
    {
        xsltTransform.Load(xsltPath, settings, new XmlUrlResolver());
    }
    xsltTransform.Transform(xmlReader, argsList, transformedXml);

    ... (Do something with transformedXml)
}
```

As I understood from MSDN, the Load method creates temporary files under the `%TEMP%` folder (In case of script enabled on the `XslCompiledTransform` object) these files are getting deleted once the call to the `Load` method is done.
My problem is that I got the following exception even when locking the `Load` method:

> Access to the path 'C:\Users\erezk\AppData\Local\Temp\iapqiwqu.tmp' is denied.

This file is one of the temporary file the `Load` call is generated.

Does anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

The `XslCompiledTransform` class has a property called `TemporaryFiles`. This will contain the filenames of the temporary files that were created during a successful `Load` call. The documentation of this property (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.xml.xsl.xslcompiledtransform.temporaryfiles(v=vs.110).aspx) says that the user can delete them after the call to `Load`. So I don't think they are deleted automatically. Hence this property wouldn't make sense otherwise.

So maybe you should try to delete them by yourself inside the lock-block.